# Setting variables for batch files in Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file named `bar.cmd` with a single line: `ECHO %Foo%`.
How can I set `Foo` in a Powershell script so that when I call `& .\bar.cmd`, it will print `Bar`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To set an environment variable in PowerShell:

```
Set-Item Env:foo "bar"
```

or

```
$env:foo = "bar"
```

If you want to do it the other way around:

When you run `cmd.exe` to execute a shell script (`.bat` or `.cmd` file) in PowerShell, the variable gets set in that running instance of `cmd.exe` but is lost when that `cmd.exe` instance terminates.

Workaround: Run the `cmd.exe` shell script and output any environment variables it sets, then set those variables in the current PowerShell session. Below is a short PowerShell function that can do this for you:

```
# Invokes a Cmd.exe shell script and updates the environment. 
function Invoke-CmdScript {
  param(
    [String] $scriptName
  )
  $cmdLine = """$scriptName"" $args & set"
  & $Env:SystemRoot\system32\cmd.exe /c $cmdLine |
    Select-String '^([^=]*)=(.*)$' | ForEach-Object {
      $varName = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
      $varValue = $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value
      Set-Item Env:$varName $varValue
    }
}
```